# Looping over data frame and saving pieces to rds results in NA.rds for fileneame

Tags: r

```
library(foreach)
targets = names(mtcars)
testing <- foreach(i = targets) %do% {
  x <- mtcars[i]
  saveRDS(x, file = paste0(targets[i], ".rds"))
  return(1) # hack to make loop not store in memory
}
```

If you run that code a new file NA.rds will appear whereas I expected `length(targets)` (11) new rds files to appear with names like "mpg.rds", "cyl.rds" etc. However, I'm left with a single rds file NA.rds.

How can I loop over a data frame and save each piece of the loop to rds where the name of the rds file is the name of the field being saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because instead of `i` (i.e. "mpg") you use `targets["mpg"]` which makes sense only when your `targets` is vector with `names(targets) == targets`. So, using your example:

```
library(foreach)
targets = names(mtcars)
targets
# [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"

testing <- foreach(i = targets) %do% {
  message(sprintf("[+] i = %s", i))
  x <- mtcars[i]
  message(sprintf("[!] But targets[i] is %s!", targets[i]))
  message(sprintf("[*] Using paste0(i, '.rds'), produces: \n%s", paste0(i, ".rds")))
  #saveRDS(x, file = paste0(i, ".rds"))
  return(1) # hack to make loop not store in memory
}

# [+] i = mpg
# [!] But targets[i] is NA!
# [*] Using paste0(i, '.rds'), produces: 
# mpg.rds
# [+] i = cyl
# [!] But targets[i] is NA!
# [*] Using paste0(i, '.rds'), produces: 
# cyl.rds
# .....................................
```